# Any books or links for information over Granthas on Vimanas?

Tags: translation-request, book-recommendation

There are some granthas on *Vimanas* like *Vaimanikashastram* by Bharadwaj Rishi and *Samaranganasutradhar* written by Bhoj Raja.

Can anyone share the name of books available or any source which is authentic enough to provide information for the same?

I want some translation in English or Hindi, especially for समरांगणसूत्रधार (Samaranganasutradhar) because it has info about aerial warfare.

Comment: If you don't have any information, then at least don't down vote.

Comment: Are you looking for them in the original Sankrit or in English translation?  By the way, the Vaimanika Shastra is widely considered a modern forgery, written less than a hundred years ago.

Comment: I want some translation in English or Hindi, especially for समरांगणसूत्रधार because it has info about aerial warfare.

Comment: http://cgpl.iisc.ernet.in/site/Portals/0/Publications/ReferedJournal/ACriticalStudyOfTheWorkVaimanikaShastra.pdf