# English / Indian references to temple Vimanas in relation to Flight

Tags: translation-request

Is an English translation/reference to the German publication available? It refers to work by Dr. V. Raghavan Emeritus Sanskrit Professor of Madras University.

[image: SriRangamTempleVimana]

It appears these are ***detachable flying  parts*** of temple Gopurams.

[Vimanas:Flying Objects from Ancient Indian Scriptures](http://transinformation.net/vimanas-die-fliegende-objekte-aus-den-altindischen-schriften/)

*Four strong liquid mercury vessels must be installed in the inner structure. When heated by Sun's rays or by other means the Vimana (aircraft) develops a powerful thrust from the mercury.*... etc.

EDITS 1/2/3

It is not totally incredible because *mercury is the heaviest known fluid* that flows and can transfer kinetic energy in a flying machine.

Several related  YouTube videos (Hindi) are appearing nowadays, we have no means to authenticate them:

https://youtu.be/KacgszbdOKE

Updated on Vimanas regarding similar wider context of Srirangam and Padmanabha temple cultures:

[Ancient Vimana Discovered in Secret Underground Chamber? Srirangam Temple, India](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TeycaiUWKbA)

( 6 min 00 secs to 11 mins 58 secs )

EDIT1:

More evidence of this past technology is appearing recently  [SriRangam Vimana by Praveen Mohan YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TeycaiUWKbA)

Comment: do you realize that the picture is Sri Rangam Vimana?

Comment: Yes, uploading another view of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any books or links for information over Granthas on Vimanas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2739/3500) and [2-line quotes on aerodynamics or air](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14344/3500)

Comment: What is your main question? If it's the one in the first line, why are you adding YouTube video links? Are you trying to convince users that "flying temple Gopurams" is real? Because it's not; it's pseudoscience. There was a controversy about this at the [2015 Indian Science Congress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Indian_Science_Congress_ancient_aircraft_controversy) - as you can see no real scientist takes these claims seriously.

Comment: Thanks for IISc. link. It is an unfortunate aspect of our ancient culture..  parts of Ramayana like the Sri Rama Sethu to Sri Lanka or Dwaraka  are seen more as an engineering "reality" from our own remote sensing images and that contemporary Ravana's flying machine Pushpaka Vimanam should regarded more fictional. Looking at contradictory narratives without being judgmental about "the reality"  is beyond the full scope of this site anyway as concerning the science of flight..

Comment: Nobody is being judgmental. When asked for evidence or a working model of a "flying vimana" one should be able to produce it. Simply showing statements made in a book/scripture/shastra is not scientific evidence. It will be summarily rejected by the scientific community. E.g., Spiderman doesn't become real if I show you a printed copy of the comic. And people believe dinosaurs once existed even when no scripture mentions it because there is fossil evidence which is undeniable.

Comment: Re: Rama Setu - satellite images are not proof that the bridge was built by humans. NASA issued a [statement](https://www.hindustantimes.com/tech-reviews/photos-no-proof-of-ram-setu-nasa/story-iSqcGrPS96TCb25hqjxF3M.html) clarifying they made no claims on how the bridge was formed/built yet lot of Indians even today continue to think NASA images are proof of the setu. If you understand Telugu watch [this](https://youtu.be/AVhZz3CsNzk) video.

Comment: As for this question, if this is a translation request of a book, then it should be limited to that. Links to YouTube videos/speculation is unnecessary.

Comment: The physical mechanism of how temple Vimana might spin is shown here on the trailer of patheyada pushpaka Vimana https://youtu.be/JMTfvGzC35c?t=19 govt broke ancient granite door, to steal and move Vimana that was underground at srirangam temple and sealed that entrance with plaster, cement. Speaking of which has anyone seen the full documentary?

Comment: It's real because in turiya, we Brahmins become same as our gods, superconductive electrical divine beings, when all nadis are purified, unlimited electricity (nature of our soul) without any loss, passes through Sushumna piercing all 7 Chakras. As well as some Vimanas are run by mantras, some by our touch thoughts (like remote, radio control) etc, but for all that spiritual one needs to be a pure turiya Brahmin or equivalent deva daivic aryan like glowing beautiful natural faced bodied slimmest either Japanese or Iranian.

Comment: also these kind of vimana are always made of gold or silver. as well as in garbhagudi as well, abundant abundant gold,slilver/copper. and all of them are superconductive, especially if pure turiya superconductive Brahmin touches, he can transfer unlimited electricity to entire Vimana. even nasa plagrised, and cover its deep space spacecrafts with gold

Comment: Also, do you know that when Mercury gets exposed to sunlight, it produces hydrogen, if used correct method? Like Shivkar Talpade did?

Comment: We may never know the truth. In those days even making steel was difficult.  What to make of an aircraft! https://www.huffingtonpost.in/open-magazine/the-myth-of-the-indian-av_b_6638684.html

Comment: As one Professor said in that article "we should not reject such claims as pseudo-science outright but examine them with intellectual curiosity."  Scientists should be open minded.   Let there be discussion and if  any sponsorship is forthcoming,  the issue should be experimented with.  @sv.

Comment: From the [same professor](https://mumbaimirror.indiatimes.com/mumbai/cover-story/Pseudo-science-must-not-figure-in-Indian-Science-Congress/articleshow/45698353.cms):  // Prof Deshpande’s study of the Vaimanika Shastra, the text Captain Bodas widely quotes from, had concluded that the text "cannot be dated earlier than 1904" and that the planes described in it are "poor concoctions" and "unimaginably horrendous from the point of view of flying" // @srimannarayanakv

Comment: I agree.  My opinion is that let there be openmindedness .  What happens if a paper is presented?   At best the community will be listening to their version.   If enthusiastic scientists should get sponsorship for put their theory into experiment.  @sv.

Comment: Aano bhadra krtavo yantu vishwatah''(1.89.1 rigveda)
 "Let noble thoughts come to me from all directions”.  So there is nothing wrong in listening a different idea, I hope.@sv.

Comment: I agree that the OP should have restricted himself to asking for English translation of the work he was looking for @sv.

Comment: "Let **noble thoughts** come to me from all directions" -  pseudoscience is not a noble thought. Nobody is stopping these so-called scientists from publishing their findings in their book or newspaper article. To publish in a scientific journal or at the science congress some minimum standards need to be met. Needs to be peer reviewed. @srimannarayanakv